# Copy a float exactly in an object attribute

Tags: customization, custom-attributes, custom-properties

I'm looking for a way to copy exactly the value of a float into the attribute of a Blender object, but I see a loss of precision on the last 5 digits.

For example I want to copy -0.18958371707600324 in `bpy.data.movieclips['untitled.png'].tracking.camera.brown_k1` and when I do:

```
bpy.data.movieclips['untitled.png'].tracking.camera.brown_k1 = -0.18958371707600324
```

It stores -0.18958371877670288 into  `bpy.data.movieclips['untitled.png'].tracking.camera.brown_k1`, instead of -0.18958371707600324.

I observe the same issue with other attributes, like `bpy.data.objects['Plane'].rotation_axis_angle[0]`.

And if I create two floats A1 and A2 so that:

```
A1 = -0.18958371707600324
A2 = 2.
A2 = A1
```

I obtain `A2 = -0.18958371707600324` so no problem here.

Any idea? The use of `decimal.Decimal` objects doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, that's a common float precision problem. As far as Blender is concerned those numbers are equal. Do you really need that amount of decimal places ? You're talking precision equivalent to the size of the smallest elementary components of matter known to man (10^-18 m). If you want to store a decimal number with an exact precision you can store it as a string and convert it to / from float when needed

Comment: Hi, so I try to simulate a specific camera with precision and I observe a small but existing shift that I associate to the loss in the various distortion parameters (brown model). I'm not sure how storing the value into a string would transfer properly the exact value to the attribute (I mean more than I did), can you please be more specific?

Comment: In other words, my problem is on transferring the value, not storing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than 5 digits precision loss:

```
-0.18958371707600324
-0.18958371877670288
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

This is basically the half precision which makes sense because `float` in Python has double precision (a.k.a. `double`) whereas Blender objects use `FloatProperty`s which have single precision, [quote](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatProperty):

> Returns a new float (single precision) property definition.

You can convince yourself with a little script that it's this loss of precision:

```
from ctypes import *
val = -0.18958371707600324   
print("double precision", c_double(val).value) # gives -0.18958371707600324
print("single precision", c_float(val).value)  # gives -0.18958371877670288
```

If you're curious, you can see the properties with:

```
for p in bpy.data.movieclips['untitled.png'].tracking.camera.bl_rna.properties:
    print(p)
```

which prints

```
...
<bpy_struct, FloatProperty("brown_k1") at 0x00007FF65AB76700>
...
```

So you are out of luck storing `-0.18958371707600324` in `brown_k1`.